# PHP combining MySQL results to one variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I'm trying to build a list of towns to add at the bottom of a site I'm working on and I can echo the variable fine within this block of PHP, however when I try to echo $result1 in another block of PHP it's only returning the first result, rather than the whole list.

Any ideas what's going on?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT town FROM jb_town_postcodes");
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
echo $results1 =  $row['town'];
```

Comment: incorrect var inside while loop, because it overrides each time until the loop ends

Comment: you just created an empty array but never used it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$results[]= $row['town'];

print_r($results);
```

Now

for example

`echo $results[0]` will print the first value e.g. Wolverhampton 
`echo $results[2]` will print Cannock

`echo $results[count($results)-1]` will print the last value

Comment: You've answered it so quickly that Stack Overflow won't actually let me accept your answer yet :D  Thanks!

Comment: how do I get it to show it not as an array, but a list of values? so rather than
"Array ( [0] => Wolverhampton [1] => Tipton [2] => Cannock [3]"
have "Wolverhampton Tipton Cannock"

Comment: for example

echo $results[0] will print Wolverhampton and 
echo $results[2] will print Cannock

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration you save in you $result1 a new value from $result - that's why after loop you have only last town.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT town FROM jb_town_postcodes");
$results = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  // at every iteration, store value of 
  // $row['town'] to new index of $results1
  $results1[] =  $row['town'];

// now use $results anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use curly brackets ;)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $results[]= $row['town']; 
}
```

Comment: If you only put 1 command inside then you should not use them to make it more readable!

Comment: @peipst9lker maybe but if you have very much lines it's better